# constructive proof that $K[X]$ is a PID

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, principal-ideal-domains, constructive-mathematics

The usual proof that $K[X]$ is a PID goes by finding $p\in I$ of the lowest degree for a non-zero ideal $I$ of $K[X]$. Constructively, this amounts to testing $p\in I$ for all $p$ of degree $0$, then for all $p$ of degree $1$, and so on.

If $K$ is infinite, the set of all polynomials of a fixed degree $n\geq 0$ is infinite, so we can't just test them all. I suppose enumerating all elements of $K[X]$ won't help either.

Surely, since $I$ is constructively non-zero, it contains a non-zero $q$, and we can factorize $q$ into irreducibles, and find $p$ among them such that $p\in I$. While this proves that $p$ is an irreducible member of $I$, this doesn't prove that $p$ is a lowest degree member of $I$.

Is there a constructive proof that $K[X]$ is a PID?

I'm specifically interested in the following ideal. Let $K\subseteq L$ be an extension of fields, let $\alpha\in L$, and $I := \{p \mid p\in K[X]; p(\alpha)=0\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal. I guess that a proof would depend on how $L$ is described. I heard there are constructive encodings of algebraic numbers. Can they help here?

Comment: What is meant by 'testing' the polynomials?

Comment: @masiewpao Running a computer program that decides whether $p\in I$ or not.

Comment: If we are checking whether $p\in I$, it must mean we have a way of 'knowing' what elements $I$ contains right? So why not just take the lowest degree polynomial of $I$, and prove this generates $I$? How come this isn't constructive?

Comment: How do you define the ideal $I$?

Comment: @Bernard For an example, read “I'm specifically interested in the following ideal …”

Comment: @masiewpao “we have a way of 'knowing' what elements I contains right? So why not just take the lowest degree polynomial of I, and prove this generates I? How come this isn't constructive?” Suppose you have a computer program $c$ that takes a polynomial $p$ and returns a boolean meaning $p\in I$. Write a computer program that returns a lowest degree polynomial of $I$; it may call $c$ to get information about $I$, of course.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I understand! Essentially the program has to prove $p$ is indeed a  poly of lowest degree, but to prove this constructively we may require $c$ to verify this correct? (Also thanks, I am very interested in reading an answer to the question).

Comment: @masiewpao In order to prove that a polynomial $p\in I$ of the lowest degree exists, we need a program returning such $p$. Any constructive proof proving existence of something should contain a program returning this something.